# Invoking shell scripts on Windows under MSYS using Command

Tags: path, command, rust, msys

I am trying to invoke commands in Rust (1.0 beta 3) on Windows 7 in an [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io) environment, but I cannot understand how to do it.

Suppose that you have this very simple script called `myls` in your home folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls
```

And now create a simple program in Rust that calls the script:

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() 
{
    let path_linux_style = Path::new("~/myls").to_str().unwrap();
    let path_win_style   = Path::new("C:\\msys64\\home\\yourname\\myls").to_str().unwrap();

    let out_linux = Command::new(path_linux_style).output();
    let out_win   = Command::new(path_win_style).output();

    match out_linux
    {
        Ok(_)  => println!("Linux path is working!"),
        Err(e) => println!("Linux path is not working: {}", e)
    }

    match out_win
    {
        Ok(_)  => println!("Win path is working!"),
        Err(e) => println!("Win path is not working: {}", e)
    }
}
```

Now, if you try to execute it, you will get the following output:

```
Linux path is not working: The system cannot find the file specified.
 (os error 2)
Win path is not working: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 (os error 193)
```

So I am not able to invoke any command in MSYS environment.
How can I solve it?

**EDIT**:
I noticed that if I invoke an executable, the problem doesn't happen, so it seems to be related to invocation of bash script. Anyway, it's quite annoying since it makes compiling projects depending on external C/C++ code (that need to launch `configure` script) tricky to get to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows example doesn't work because Windows isn't a Unix. On Unix-like systems, the `#!` at the beginning of a script is recognized, and it invokes the executable at the given path as the interpreter. Windows doesn't have this behavior; and even if it did, it wouldn't recognize the path name to the `/bin/bash`, as that path name is one that msys2 emulates, it is not a native path name.

Instead, you can explicitly execute the script you want using the msys2 shell, by doing something like the following (alter the path as appropriate, I have `msys32` installed since it's a 32 bit VM)

```
let out_win   = Command::new("C:\\msys32\\usr\\bin\\sh.exe")
                            .arg("-c")
                            .arg(path_win_style)
                            .output();
```